# How to parse string to xml at asp.net mvc and output it?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I`m looking for possibility to parse some input text at xml output.

Such tool **XmlSerializer** did not help me, and I have no idea how to output xml at view.

Thank you for any help.

There is simple model for string input:

```
[XmlRoot("Text")]
public class StringModel
{
    public int InputStringId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Sentence")]
    public string InputString { get; set; }
}
```

Controller, where I have tried with XMLSerialized, but it`s not working

```
public class StringController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetString(List<StringModel> line)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<StringModel>));
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:StringModel.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, line);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You should use `XElement`.

Comment: what do you mean "output it"?  If you just want to display it on the screen, you could just encode the xml string with [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx), and display it as a string

Comment: @SLaks  Why should he use `XElement`?  In fact, why should he deserialize the xml at all??

Comment: @Vlad_Sobko If you want the user to download it as a file, you can return a [FileResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx) from your controller.

Comment: @Sam I am  I have meant "output it" to show at view. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class will generate an XML file, its possible this will give your some guidance.

```
  public static class XMLOutput
    {
        public static void XMLProductOutput(product product, string path) {

            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(path))
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Envelope");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ProductMasterUpdate");
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ProdCode", product.ProdCode.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Length", product.Length.ToString() ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Width", product.Width.ToString() ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Lip", product.Height.ToString() ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("MatCat", product.MATCATEGORY.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("UPC1", product.UPCCODE ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("UPC2", product.UPCCODE2 ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("UPC3", product.UPCCODE3 ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PLU", product.PLU ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("ManufacturerCode", product.ManufacturerCode.ToString() ?? String.Empty.ToString());
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Specs", product.SpecComments ?? String.Empty.ToString());

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to accomplish though. Perhaps you want to display it in a view?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"D:StringModel.xml");
ViewData[xmlData] = doc.ToString();
```

Then in the view you can

```
XDocument.Parse(ViewData[xmlData]).ToString()
```

Comment: thank you. Yes, I want to convert string to xml and result show at view.